# python - cant parse text from a site but from mine can

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, parsing, beautifulsoup

im strugling with a site here is my code

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get('https://fmdataba.com/20/p/220045/diego-barbosa',headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36'})


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
physical = {}
technical = {}

table = soup.find_all('table',{'class':'table tab61'})
print(len(table))
trs = table[0].find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all("td")
    if len (tds) ==2:
        physical[tds[0].text] = tds[1].text
print(physical)

table = soup.find_all('table',{'class':'table tab61'})
trs = table[1].find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all("td")
    if len (tds) ==2:
        technical[tds[0].text] = tds[1].text
print(technical)
```

the thing is that i need to parse the hability of players but it gives me everytime this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marco\Desktop\fmdata.py", line 17, in <module>
    trs = table[1].find_all('tr')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

i got a copy of part of the html file in my site

http://pes6indie.tk/test.html

if i try against this, it works, but not to the actual site

Comment: `soup` slurped: `<h3>bad activity detected, please contact moderator.</h3><h2>y.e.ygt@hotmail.com</h2>` - that might be the problem.

Comment: So... the site owner is blocking the site from scraping?

Comment: It's called 'scraping'. yes. But you can circumvent that with better headers when requesting.

Comment: Sorry, english aint my first language, i reasearch for headers and to my code i just added
page = requests.get('https://fmdataba.com/20/p/220045/diego-barbosa',headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36'})

now i dont get that message, but i still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the owner of the site is blocking scraping attempts in one form or another. You get the list index error because there will be a page (something like a 501 forbidden) with an error message which probably does not have a second table attribute.

It might be safer in such cases to do either (or both) of 2 things:

1. Check up front the lenght of your list to detect if you even have a
   second element.
2. Check if said supplier of information has an (REST)
   API available for you. This is a way neater and more structured way
   to collect the data.

[EDIT]
Also: You can check with requests for the status code. This will be something like a 200 for succes and others for different failure states. Any decent site will provide the error code at that point, making it trivial to stop scraping before the first error is hit.

Comment: By the way im searching the table there is only 3 elements, also, sadly there's not API for this site, there's not any other workaround?

Comment: Maybe the question should be the other way around. Keep using the code you have now but be more conservative (that is, check for elements to exist before querying them). Also, when using pdb (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) you can step through the code on a more finegrained level. You can manually inspect the elements which in your case is perfectly doable. There you can probably determine why you get the results you do. For now, it's just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the link that you provided:

https://fmdataba.com/20/p/220045/diego-barbosa

and for the current instance of it, it doesn't contain an element with a class "table tab61".

The phrase "tab61" isn't even in the page's html.

You're getting index out of range because there is no tab61 class in the html

Comment: Thanks a lot! your answer make me realized that i was missing at end of the url a "/"
also thanks to @Gwang-Jin Kim for telling me about the headers